# Add "follow-mode" status to Emacs modeline

Tags: emacs

How can I add an indicator to the Emacs modeline to indicate that `follow-mode` is enabled in the current buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
(push (list 'follow-mode " Follow") minor-mode-alist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive way that works

```
(push '(:eval (if follow-mode "Following... " "")) global-mode-string)
```

but do refer to the documentation of `mode-line-format` using `C-h v`, as `global-mode-string` could be abusive in this case.